# SIFT with Emgu : How can I solve error : 'INVERT METHOD' does not exist in the namespace 'Emgu.CV.CvEnum'

Tags: emgucv, sift

I download sift implementation from : https://sites.google.com/site/btabibian/projects/3d-reconstruction/code
but i get the error : 'INVERT METHOD' does not exist in the namespace 'Emgu.CV.CvEnum'. from code line : `CvInvoke.cvInvert(H, H_inv.Ptr, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INVERT_METHOD.CV_SVD);` any suggestion to solve my problem?

Comment: Did you end up compiling the project and using it?

Answer (score 1):

This sample uses a very old version of EmguCV: 2.0.1.0.
The current version is 3.0.

You have to change the `CvInvoke.CvInvert()` call into `CvInvoke.Invert()`. The third method parameter is of type `Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DecompMethod`, so you have to change `INVERT_METHOD.CV_SVD` into `DecompMethod.Svd`.

Comment: about version you are right. but when i change the code, many other errors create. maybe i should find another code for sift. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

from

```
 CvInvoke.cvInvert(H, H_inv.Ptr, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INVERT_METHOD.CV_SVD);
```

to

```
 CvInvoke.cvInvert(H, H_inv.Ptr, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.SOLVE_METHOD.CV_SVD);
```

change to that work with me

but i still dont know how to add image to the project to use sift algorithm on them

did anyone have arunning project using sift to mack 3d object from many images?

Comment: Did you end up solving your issue? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code line to the following resolved the issue for me on version 2.4.9:

```
CvInvoke.cvInvert(H, H_inv.Ptr, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.SOLVE_METHOD.CV_SVD);
```